# Dict Javascript my_dict = {'A':'test','B':'test'}: why my_dict['A'] return undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I pass a dictionary `my_dict` to my JS code and `console.log(my_dict)` return my_dict

But when I try to access a value through a key, it returns 'undefined' while the key 'A' exists?

what is wrong?

```
my_dict= $("#my_dict").data('my_dict');
console.log(my_dict); // display my_dict in my console
console.log(my_dict['A']); // display undefined in my console
```

Comment: Are you including the return in your code, or are you just putting pseudocode so we see what it's returning?

Comment: Could you show us how the element data is being set?

Comment: Object { A: "Polyvitamine et Oligo-éléments", B: "Hydorxychloroquine", C: "Favipiravir", D: "Imatinib", E: "Telmisartan" }

Comment: @SLATER is this the real code? Those keys should be quoted (`"A": "...."` etc).

Comment: @Jon: no it is console.log(my_dict) that is displayed

Answer (score 1):

This data attr does not return an array, it returns the object.

Try to fetch ket value pair like we fetch from object

like

`my_dict.A`

have a look to the code below

```js
$("#my_dict").data( "my_dict", { A: 'test', B: "test" });
debugger;
var my_dict = $("#my_dict").data('my_dict');
console.log(my_dict); // display my_dict in my console
console.log(my_dict.A);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_dict">
</div>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between `obj.A` and `obj['A']`, both should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value contains quotes, try the following:

```js
$("#my_dict").data( "my_dict",  { A: "Polyvitamine et Oligo-éléments", B: "Hydorxychloroquine", C: "Favipiravir", D: "Imatinib", E: "Telmisartan" } );

var my_dict = $("#my_dict").data('my_dict');

var my_dict_2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( $("#my_dict").data('my_dict')));

console.log(my_dict['A']);
console.log(my_dict_2['A']);

// both work perfectly
// Now I'm guessing you're data is wrapped with quotes ''
// noting that props should be between double quotes "" ("A" instead of A - which is an invalid JSON string)

$("#my_dict").data( "my_dict",  '{ "A": "Polyvitamine et Oligo-éléments", "B": "Hydorxychloroquine", "C": "Favipiravir", "D": "Imatinib", "E": "Telmisartan" }' );

my_dict = $("#my_dict").data('my_dict');

my_dict_2 = JSON.parse($("#my_dict").data('my_dict'));

// this will give you undefined
console.log(my_dict['A']);

// parsing the string will work
console.log(my_dict_2['A']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_dict"></div>
```